# In Google cloud, Language texts not displayed in proper way

Tags: php, html, google-app-engine

I have a piece of code in html and php for my index.php. This page is used for users to register. The users inserts its details and the registration process works successfully. The user can insert its details written in every language, and all characters are recognized and displayed in the right format. That works fine in localhost in my laptop using xampp. When I uploading my code to google cloud, however a problem occurs. If the user register himself with text lets say in Russian language, then in my database text stored in a strange format like **& upsilon ;** etc Probably the problem here is that when I upload my code to google cloud, not all language formats are read in the proper way. Any ideas on how to fix this?

This is my code:

```
<?php  
  include 'init.php';
?>

 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css">
 <title> My page </title>
</head>


<body> 

----------here is the form where the user register

</body> 
</html>
```

my problem is that when a user

Comment: The problem could be in two places, the database and in the actual requests. Are you encoding your requests using UTF-?

Comment: my database was set to utf8mb4_general_ci . I have just alter it to this format. Still storing text in this strange format.

Comment: i have also checked my tables and they are in InnoDB, latin1_swedish_ci

Comment: But are the actual requests being encoded?

Comment: you mean if my form posts data using the right encode format?

Comment: Yes, try to verify that before you save in the datastore you get the actual String as UFT-8

Comment: I have add to my form this  <form  accept-charset="utf-8"> still nothing...